# Liquibase precondition MARK_RAN, rollback executes

Tags: java, liquibase

I'm using version 3.6.1

I have an insert script with a precondition. If the precondition fails the result is a MARK_RAN in databaseChangelog table, but when I try to rollback, the rollback statement is executed, resulting in an error.

I found some old threads with the same issue but I'm not sure how to handle this case.

https://forum.liquibase.org/t/preconditions-and-custom-rollback/477

https://forum.liquibase.org/t/rollback-runs-if-precondition-fails/1896/2

I don't have write rights in all enviroments so the precondition would not fail anymore.

Comment: Could you share the changeset in question?  Does this happen using the latest 3.10.2 or 4.x versions?

Comment: I cannot share the code, sorry. I haven't tried the latest versions